# jQuery(" ").datepicker({ }) is not working in IE7/8

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors

**My code is**

```
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery("#fromDatepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth : true,
            changeYear : true,
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
        });
    });
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery("#toDatepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth : true,
            changeYear : true,
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
        });
    });
```

and input fields are

```
<input type="text" id="fromDatepicker" name="searchStartDate"  size="20">
<input type="text" id="fromDatepicker" name="searchStartDate"  size="20">
```

the calender is displaying but,

when I select a date on the calendar, the date is not selecting and not entering the date into the text field.

i am using

1. jquery-1.6.2.js
2. jquery-1.6.2.min.js
3. jquery.ui.core.js
4. jquery.ui.datepicker.js
5. jquery.ui.datepicker.css

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Next time, you can format source code with the `{}` toolbar button. (I haven't done it myself 'cos I don't want to remove the `<br>` tags.)

Comment: @NAVEED what was wrong with my edit

Comment: @3nigma: Use `{}` button to format code to its original format. No need to use `<br />` in code for formatting..

Answer (score 1):

You are including the same version of jQuery twice, jquery-1.6.2.js and jquery-1.6.2.min.js. Just load the latter and this should stop some of the issues you are having.

Additionally, you have unnecessarily put the code into 2 `jQuery();` calls, they could be put into one like this

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#fromDatepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true,
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
    });

    jQuery("#toDatepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true,
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
    });
});
```

Comment: I removed the  jquery-1.6.2.min.js and tested, no use, it is giving same problem. when i select date from Calendar, it is not responding.

Comment: Judging from your example, your inputs have the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this entire thing a bit:

```
<input type="text" id="fromDatepicker"  size="20" />
<input type="text" id="toDatepicker"  size="20" /> 


jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#fromDatepicker, #toDatepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
    });
});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/jUsTr/

By putting the comma between the selectors they are two selectors.